# Log HTTP status code to Google Analytics Custom Dimension

Tags: google-analytics, custom-error-pages, ghost-blog, gtag.js

I'm trying to keep track of pages that result in errors on my Ghost blog. A live error page can be found here:

https://jessehouwing.net/404/

To do this I've added the following code to the error pages.

### Header

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-29964481-1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-29964481-1', {
    'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'statusCode'}
  });
</script>
```

### Footer

```
<script>
    gtag('event', 'httpError', { 'statusCode': 404 });
</script>
```

And created my custom dimension in the Analytics portal for this property:

[image]

And in the Developer Console I can see the request being made:

[image]

Yet the event doesn't show up in the analytics portal

### My question(s)

How can I debug this without entering random data?! And what should I put in the configuration / error page template to see pages hitting this event?

Comment: Wouldn't displaying the 404 page indicate that it is a 404 error? In this case, the page that was requested might be more of value to keep.

Comment: That's exactly what the script does. The 404 page itself doesn't exist ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been correct all along, except that Google Analytics doesn't seem to be interested in TODAY by default and reports up until the end of yesterday:

[image]

Comment: It's normal thing in google analytics. Data processing can take up even to 48h (usually 24 hours)! More here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en

Comment: Is there a way to, temporarily, or even a single IP, force faster processing or verify a setup? It's a nightmare to debug this way...

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to force in free GA faster data processing (sometimes ga show current day data [but it depends]). You can debug requests by webdev network tab (just like you do this now). In some cases real time reports (in GA panel) are useful to debug but they don't show custom dimmensions and other more advanced stuff. Of course you can also try "Google Analytics Debugger" (chrome extension) but to be honest: it won't show you much more than you can check manualy in browser "network" tab (it just shows request made to GA in nice and formatted way in console)

Comment: Thanks. You wonder how the marketing folks get all this stuff working...